# Irfanview plugin to upload to imagehosting sites?

Tags: images, irfanview

Is there such a plug-in available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload images from the Thumbnail Browser:

**File** menu, **Transfer selected files by FTP**

(some image hosting services such as **[Photobucket](http://tutorials.photobucket.com/tutorial_7.html)** support FTP transfer)